# Plot marker on map from autocomplete item clicked produces Class Cast Exception

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, classcastexception, autocompletetextview

I am able to get all suggestion from AutocompleteTextView. When i click on a suggestion item i want to plot the latitude and longitude coordinates associated with that particular item. Currently i am displaying that suggestion as a String but when i try to convert it to Object to get the latitude and longitude coordinates i get Class Cast Exception. I really need help here.

**This is my method below**

```
private void searchAutocomplete(){
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //Create a new ArrayAdapter with your context and the simple layout for the dropdown menu provided by Android
    final ArrayAdapter<String> autoComplete = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    //Child the root before all the push() keys are found and add a ValueEventListener()
    database.child("wr").child("clubs").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Basically, this says "For each DataSnapshot *Data* in dataSnapshot, do what's inside the method.
            for (DataSnapshot suggestionSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                //Get the suggestion by childing the key of the string you want to get.
                String suggestion = suggestionSnapshot.child("name1").getValue(String.class);
                //Add the retrieved string to the list
                autoComplete.add(suggestion);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    final AutoCompleteTextView ACTV= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autocompleteView);
    ACTV.setAdapter(autoComplete);
    ACTV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
        {
            LocationModel currentLocation =(LocationModel) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

            double latitude = currentLocation.getLat();
            double longitude = currentLocation.getLng();

            LatLngBounds bounds;
            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

            // Create LatLng for each locations
            LatLng mLatlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            // Make sure the map boundary contains the location
            builder.include(mLatlng);
            bounds = builder.build();


            //markerList.add(mMarker);

            // Zoom map to the boundary that contains every logged location
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
                    MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL));



        }
    });

}
```

**Error Log**

```
4 12045-12045/com.lawerh.jonathan.partygoer V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView{a5ff873 VFED..CL. .F....ID 0,0-688,85 #7f1000d9 app:id/autocompleteView} ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@f770cf2 tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ce6f43 controlFlags=#0
01-14 07:10:24.015 12045-12045/com.lawerh.jonathan.partygoer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-14 07:10:24.016 12045-12045/com.lawerh.jonathan.partygoer E/UncaughtException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.lawerh.jonathan.partygoer.model.LocationModel
                                                                                      at com.lawerh.jonathan.partygoer.ui.MapActivity$4.onItemClick(MapActivity.java:107)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:920)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.-wrap1(AutoCompleteTextView.java)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1217)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:315)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1193)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3231)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4207)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
01-14 07:10:24.023 12045-12075/com.lawerh.jonathan.partygoer D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae, Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=MapActivity, _si=1784221226449878799, timestamp=1484377824016, fatal=1}]
```

Comment: post your error log

Comment: You adapter contains a list of objects of type `String`. You can't magically pull out an object of type `LocationModel` from the adapter.

Comment: how can i retrieve the other details from the String value